# Terms added to custom taxonomy for custom post type only appear in Rest when added in code

Tags: custom-taxonomy, rest-api

Nothing to do with what I thought at all. The issue is pagination. Need to add ?per_page=100 to get more than 10. According to a comment on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462187/wordpress-rest-api-v2-how-to-list-taxonomy-terms) if you have more than 100 you need to use pagination.

Comment: Our site is a question and answers site. :) Could you please split your post into these two parts? Describe the problem you faced in the question and the code that solved it in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone makes the same mistake - I had added 20 terms via the UI  but only 10 showed up in Rest calls. I added a few more in code wp_insert_term - and these showed up in rest calls. i assumed that was the issue but it seems something to do with ordering - which is why the ones added in code showed up. Actual issue was paginaton.